# Ember data loads into store, won't show up on page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an ember application that connects to a separate phoenix API. I'm using the `ActiveModelAdapter` and everything was working fine until I upgraded my ember version to 2.1.0. Now, the data will load into the store but won't show up on the page. My browser's console isn't throwing any errors and I'm just stumped at this point. I've never worked with this version of Ember before so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

My adapter:

```
# app/adapters/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
 namespace: 'v1',
 host: 'http://localhost:4000'
});
```

My router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';  
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({  
location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {  
  this.route('resources', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('resource', { path: '/:resource_id' });
    });
});
```

My model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({  
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  topic: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
  editResource: function() {
    this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
  },
  saveResource: function() {
    var resource = this.get('model');
    resource.save();
    this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
    }, 
  },

  isEditing: false
});
```

My template for the index page to list all of the resources:

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each resource in model}}
     <li class="list-group-item active">
      {{#link-to 'resources.resource' resource}}
         <h5>{{resource.title}}</h5> 
     {{/link-to}}</li>
     <li class="list-group-item"><p>topic: {{resource.topic}}</p></li>
     <li class="list-group-item"><p>url: {{resource.url}}</p></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I see in the browser console when I try to visit my index page route: localhost:4200/resources

[image]

[image]

In the ember data inspector, my four resources are there, but the do not show up on the page. At the same time, no errors in the console.

Again, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

also if anyone is interested my repo is here, the branch i'm working on is unit-tests:

https://github.com/SophieDeBenedetto/flybrary-front/tree/unit-tests

UPDATE: Thanks to @dfreeman my index template is rendering correctly now but my show page to render an individual model object is still blank:

```
<div class="well col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" style="text-align: center;"        {{bind-attr class="resource.isShowing:show resource.isEditing:editing"}}>

{{#if model.isEditing}}
  <input class="edit">{{model.title}}  
  <p class="edit" >{{model.url}}</p> 
  <p class="edit" >topic: {{model.topic}}</p> 
  <p class="edit" >description: {{model.description}}</p>   
{{else}}
  <h4 class="toggle" {{action "editResource" on="doubleClick"}}>      {{model.title}}</h4>  
  <p class="toggle" {{action "editResource" on="doubleClick"}}>   {{model.url}}</p> 
  <p class="toggle" {{action "editResource" on="doubleClick"}}>topic:   {{model.topic}}</p> 
  <label class="toggle" {{action "editResource" on="doubleClick"}}>description: {{model.description}}</label>
  {{/if}}
  <p>{{#link-to 'resources.resource.edit' model}}Edit{{/link-to}}</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your `bind-attr` in the `show` template is still bound to "resource.isShowing", I think you want "model.isShowing" maybe? Also, you can get rid of `bind-attr` and should use the updated method of binding dynamic content - http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr

Answer (score 0):

The `{{#each x in y}}` version of the `each` helper was [removed in Ember 2.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-breaking-changes-in-ember-2-0). Back in 1.10, a [new generalized block syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params) was introduced to take its place.

If you change out your template to use the new syntax, you should be good to go.

```
{{#each model as |resource|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks @dfreeman! my index page is rendering correctly now but my show page to render an individual resource object is still blank. Any ideas? I'll copy and paste that template at the bottom of my original question above.

Comment: @SophieDeBenedetto your `resources.hbs` has to have an `{{outlet}}` to render the content of the nested routes. Check this http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes